# How can I find out if there is a Gameobject at position xy in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to find out if there is a Gameobject at a specific location in Unity2D. Is there a way on how I can do it?

Comment: assuming your objects have colliders, you can cast a ray at the location and see if it hits anything

Answer (score 3):

## Whatever you're doing that needs this design requirement is flawed. But...

You have three options:

1. Fix your design so that you don't need this (e.g. store a list/array/dictionary of any object you're interested in and use that instead). I.E. this question is raising an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) red flag.
2. Fire a ray into the scene and see if it hits anything. Be careful here, a ray that starts *inside* a collider will ignore that collider (alternatively, use `OverlapSphere`). Desired searched objects must also have a collider attached.
3. Iterate over the entire transform hierarchy of the scene and check the position of each game object (warning: position is a floating point value, be careful when comparing floats!).